# SparkStreaming: avoid checkpointLocation check

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I'm writing a library to integrate Apache Spark with a custom environment. I'm implementing both custom streaming sources and streaming writers.

Some of the sources I'm developing are not recoverable, at least after a crash of the application. If an application is restarted, it needs to reload all the data.
Therefore we would like to avoid the users to have to set explicitly the 'checkpointLocation' option.
But if the option is not provided, we see the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: checkpointLocation must be specified either through option("checkpointLocation", ...) or SparkSession.conf.set("spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation", ...);
```

However, if I use the console stream output, everything works fine.

Is there a way to obtain the same behavior?

Note: we are using the Spark v2 interfaces for our stream readers/writers.

---

Spark log:

```
18/06/29 16:36:48 INFO SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir ('file:/C:/mydir/spark-warehouse/').
18/06/29 16:36:48 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/C:/mydir/spark-warehouse/'.
18/06/29 16:36:48 INFO StateStoreCoordinatorRef: Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: checkpointLocation must be specified either through option("checkpointLocation", ...) or SparkSession.conf.set("spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation", ...);
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager$$anonfun$3.apply(StreamingQueryManager.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager$$anonfun$3.apply(StreamingQueryManager.scala:208)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager.createQuery(StreamingQueryManager.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager.startQuery(StreamingQueryManager.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:296)
    ...
18/06/29 16:36:50 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

This is how I start the streaming job:

```
spark.readStream().format("mysource").load()
  .writeStream().format("mywriter").outputMode(OutputMode.Append()).start();
```

Everything works fine, instead, if for example I run:

```
spark.readStream().format("mysource").load()
  .writeStream().format("console").outputMode(OutputMode.Append()).start();
```

---

I cannot share the full code of the data writer. Anyway, I did something like this:

```
class MySourceProvider extends DataSourceRegister with StreamWriteSupport {
  def createStreamWriter(queryId: String, schema: StructType, mode: OutputMode, options: DataSourceOptions): StreamWriter = {
    new MyStreamWriter(...)
  }
  def shortName(): String = {
    "mywriter"
  }
}

class MyStreamWriter(...) extends StreamWriter { 
  def abort(epochId: Long, messages: Array[WriterCommitMessage]): Unit = {}
  def commit(epochId: Long, messages: Array[WriterCommitMessage]): Unit = {}
  def createWriterFactory(): DataWriterFactory[Row] = {
    new MyDataWriterFactory()
  }
}
```

Comment: could you please add full log and code sample

Comment: I added the log content and some code snippet. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need  to add checkpointLocation in your code

> option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/vaquarkhan/checkpoint"). // <--
>   checkpoint directory

**Example :**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.{OutputMode, Trigger}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
val q = records.
  writeStream.
  format("console").
  option("truncate", false).
  option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/vaquarkhan/checkpoint"). // <-- checkpoint directory
  trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(10.seconds)).
  outputMode(OutputMode.Update).
  start
```

Regardig your question  have  following  three choices:

> .option("startingOffsets", "latest") // read data from the end of the
>   stream

- earliest — start reading at the beginning of the stream. This excludes data that has already been deleted from Kafka because it was older than the retention period (“aged out” data).
- latest — start now, processing only new data that arrives after the query has started.
- per-partition assignment — specify the precise offset to start from for every partition, allowing fine-grained control over exactly where processing should start. For example, if we want to pick up exactly where some other system or query left off, then this option can be leveraged.

If the directory name for the checkpoint location could not be found, createQuery reports a AnalysisException.

```
checkpointLocation must be specified either through option("checkpointLocation", ...) or SparkSession.conf.set("spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation", ...)
```

Following is apache spark code:

```
  private def createQuery(
      userSpecifiedName: Option[String],
      userSpecifiedCheckpointLocation: Option[String],
      df: DataFrame,
      extraOptions: Map[String, String],
      sink: BaseStreamingSink,
      outputMode: OutputMode,
      useTempCheckpointLocation: Boolean,
      recoverFromCheckpointLocation: Boolean,
      trigger: Trigger,
      triggerClock: Clock): StreamingQueryWrapper = {
    var deleteCheckpointOnStop = false
    val checkpointLocation = userSpecifiedCheckpointLocation.map { userSpecified =>
      new Path(userSpecified).toUri.toString
    }.orElse {
      df.sparkSession.sessionState.conf.checkpointLocation.map { location =>
        new Path(location, userSpecifiedName.getOrElse(UUID.randomUUID().toString)).toUri.toString
      }
    }.getOrElse {
      if (useTempCheckpointLocation) {
        // Delete the temp checkpoint when a query is being stopped without errors.
        deleteCheckpointOnStop = true
        Utils.createTempDir(namePrefix = s"temporary").getCanonicalPath
      } else {
        throw new AnalysisException(
          "checkpointLocation must be specified either " +
            """through option("checkpointLocation", ...) or """ +
            s"""SparkSession.conf.set("${SQLConf.CHECKPOINT_LOCATION.key}", ...)""")
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But I was actually wondering whether it is possible to avoid that check on the checkpointLocation option, since it seems that if I use the console output it is not required. I was trying at least to understand the reason behind this behavior.

Comment: You cannot avoid it, if you have any usecase share with apache spark mailing list or create Jira with problem sample code and data andall posiible testcase https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/SPARK/summary

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. In the Spark code I see 'useTempCheckpointLocation' and 'recoverFromCheckpointLocation' in the constructor, therefore it seems that there is a way to tune this behavior. Do you know if and how it is actually possible?

Comment: Hi, I found the answer: this behavior is hardcoded in the Spark DataStreamWriter start() method. Thanks for your help.